# RoR Graphql Types::BaseObject NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, graphql

When making a graphql API request to my rails backend I get the following error in my `app/graphql/types/query_type.rb`:

```
Started POST "/graphql" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-04-06 13:27:07 +0200
Processing by GraphqlController#execute as */*
  Parameters: {...}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 266ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3660)



NameError (uninitialized constant Types::BaseObject):

app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:2:in `<module:Types>'
app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:1:in `<main>'
...
```

This is the QueryType class:

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    field :discord_user, DiscordUserType, null: true do
      argument :id, ID, required: true
    end

    def discord_user(id:)
      DiscordUser.find(id)
    end

    field :discord_users, [DiscordUserType], null: false

    def discord_users
      DiscordUser.all
    end
  end
end
```

I myself did not find an error with the naming conventions and since the BaseObject is provided by the `graphql` gem I don't know why there should be an error with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to have nested it wrongly.

```rb
module Types # Types here 
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject # Types
    field :discord_user, DiscordUserType, null: true do
      argument :id, ID, required: true
    end

    def discord_user(id:)
      DiscordUser.find(id)
    end

    field :discord_users, [DiscordUserType], null: false

    def discord_users
      DiscordUser.all
    end
  end
end
```

try

```rb
module Types  
  class QueryType < BaseObject 
    field :discord_user, DiscordUserType, null: true do
      argument :id, ID, required: true
    end

    def discord_user(id:)
      DiscordUser.find(id)
    end

    field :discord_users, [DiscordUserType], null: false

    def discord_users
      DiscordUser.all
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you define BaseObject?
Make sure you have BaseObject defined in
-> app/graphql/types/base_object.rb

```rb
module Types
  class BaseObject < GraphQL::Schema::Object
    field_class Types::BaseField
  end
end
```